# DynamoDB scan returns incomplete data

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a full scan on a dynamoDB tables. This is the code I am using:

```
private void fetchItems(AmazonDynamoDBClient client) {
    int count = 0;
    ScanResult result = null;
    ScanRequest req = new ScanRequest();
    req.setTableName(this.tableName);
    do {
        if (result != null) {
            req.setExclusiveStartKey(result.getLastEvaluatedKey());
        }
        result = client.scan(req);
        List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> rows = result.getItems();
        count += rows.size();
    } while(result.getLastEvaluatedKey() != null);
        System.out.println("Result size: " + count);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this functions returns 207 of the 273 items that are in the table. I have checked the metrics and there has been no throttling of requests. What could be the reason for this incomplete result ?

Comment: If you sum up the size of `result.getItems()` over your loop, does it make the same number? Do they all have attribute `STUDENT_ID`? Is this the exact code that gives you the problem, or a simplified version of it for the question? (if it's a simplified version, you may have removed the bug).  As a note, throttling would throw an exception, not give missing results.

Comment: Also, is your client set to use the credentials and region you expect? You might have different results in a table in a different region or account than you're validating against (ie: beta vs prod account, or us-east-1 vs us-west-1).

Comment: @Chris  I have edited the code to show the exact one that's giving the problem. As for the credentials thing, I will get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was looking at the wrong region. The table I was reading from was in NA while I was looking at the EU one. Thanks to @Chris for this.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Your code looked fine, and I've done the same thing myself before :)